# How do I change to use the same route :id as update instead of :model_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-routes

I have these routes

```
  resources :brokers do
    patch :approve
```

`rake routes`

```
        broker_approve PATCH  /brokers/:broker_id/approve(.:format)       brokers#approve
                       PATCH  /brokers/:id(.:format)                      brokers#update
```

The URL is `http://localhost:3000/brokers/1/approve`.

It gives error

> Couldn't find Broker with 'id'=

The controller which loads the broker is

```
def set_broker
  @broker = Broker.find(params[:id])
```

The parameters are

```
{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"O8jztBqgRPcepes/p6IQqTfUQ==", "broker_id"=>"1"}
```

How can I use the path `/brokers/:id/approve` like how `#update` does so it can use the same method to load the model?

Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by updating your routes to

```
resources :brokers do
    member do
      patch :approve
    end
end
```

which would treat the nested route as a member route. This would create a route as  follows:

```
approve_broker PATCH  /brokers/:id/approve(.:format) brokers#approve
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
  resources :brokers do
    patch :approve, on: :member
```

yields

```
>rake routes | grep approve
            approve_broker PATCH  /brokers/:id/approve(.:format)              brokers#approve
```

I had to change the path around, but that's fine.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions